# AEM Display DeActivate Later time

Tags: aem

In AEM (Adobe Experience Manager 6.2) a user can select a page to be "Activated Later" (Publish Later) and choose a date/time.  The Notifications display will show "Waiting for activation" with the date/time.  This is great.  But when a page is scheduled for deactivation using the "DeActivate Later" (UnPublish Later), the Notification does not contain the date/time.  Is there a way to add text to the comments section of a notification to include the date/time?  Or trigger AEM to fill it in?

Notifications:

[image]

Comment: This is by design in AEM. You cannot display the information unless you overlay this interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of difference in workflow model of both requests.
workflow model for activation request

[image: workflow model for activation request]

workflow model for deactivation request:

[image: workflow model for deactivation request:]

As you can see there is a Create version step in activation request. I think this step is setting above message.

If you want to create the unpublished version for your page, you can add the same step to deactivation model or create your own process step for adding the time stamp, then add the same to the deactivation model.

It should work.

Comment: The create version step does not set a time. It creates a version. The timestamp displayed in scheduled activation message is for the job schedule.

Comment: Thank you Pooja Chauhan for pointing me in the right direction.  I don't want to create a new version, but the CreateVersionProcess.execute() method has a line in it:
data.getMetaDataMap().put("comment", "Activate version " + revStr + " on " + cal.getTime().toString());
Which is what I need to do in my new workflow step.  I will try and report back on how it works.

Comment: @AlexHomeBrew , Glad it Helps !!!..  If you find the comment helpful give a upvote plz